# Does SVN keep changes locally on your hard disk

Tags: svn, version-control

Say, If I don't have internet connection, and I want to see a previous version, is that possible with SVN. In other words, does it save the differences locally on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion keeps a pristine copy of the "base" (i.e. the latest version that you checked out or updated to) in the .svn folder at the root of your working copy.

This means you can find out which files have been modified in your local working copy with `svn status` and see what the modifications are with `svn diff` without a connection to the server. You can also `svn revert` things back to the base revision.

However, you cannot examine changes made by a particular commit unless you have a connection to the repository.

Comment: Ah that is bad. Is it possible to ask the server to give you all the changes for all the commits. I'm asking because I have a project on assembla and it keeps me reminding that my quota for that project is over. So I fear they might delete it. If I can save it somewhere, at least I would have all the changes with me.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: you can replicate the full history in another subversion repository with the [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnsync.html) tool.

Comment: Is there a way to also download the full repository with revisions on your hard drive?

Comment: Yes, create a local repository (e.g. TortoiseSVN - "Create repository here") and then use svnsync with the file: url of that folder as the target. You can also repeatedly sync to keep your local mirror up to date, as long as you don't commit to the mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Because of SVN is a Client-Server-System you **won't be able** to see/checkout a previous version. All informations you need are on the server. What you can see "offline" is a change-compare (`show changes`).

Full offline access  is possible with GIT.

(Assuming your SVN-Repository is on a Server and not on local machine)